# iterating nested js objects

Tags: javascript, react-native, javascript-objects

i've had trouble accessing this Object :

```
{
  "BTC": {
    "price": 13322.848306438736,
    "percent_change_24h": 2.00659441,
    "market_cap": 246870460628.15366,
    "volume_24h": 33956399259.1725,
    "circulating_supply": 18529856,
    "total_supply": 18529856,
    "max_supply": 21000000
  },
  "ETH": {
    "price": 380.8150073343507,
    "percent_change_24h": -0.67132589,
    "market_cap": 43115533610.355606,
    "volume_24h": 15706287212.275429,
    "circulating_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "total_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "max_supply": null
  }
}
```

and so far i've tried Object.key() , map(), making it an array, algorithmic methods and so on.
i could get the list of outer objects by :

```
Object.keys(this.state.dataApi).map((value,key)=>(
                   value
                  ))
```

i could get what's inside "BTC" for example as an object by :

```
this.state.dataApi.BTC
```

but i wasn't able to get its inner elements one by one.
this is the expected output example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK8Ic.png

these are my output successful tries

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK6lR.png

Note: this also tried changing type from the state [] , {} , "" , only "" got me a bit somewhere as it leaves the object in its original type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let obj= {
  "BTC": {
    "price": 13322.848306438736,
    "percent_change_24h": 2.00659441,
    "market_cap": 246870460628.15366,
    "volume_24h": 33956399259.1725,
    "circulating_supply": 18529856,
    "total_supply": 18529856,
    "max_supply": 21000000
  },
  "ETH": {
    "price": 380.8150073343507,
    "percent_change_24h": -0.67132589,
    "market_cap": 43115533610.355606,
    "volume_24h": 15706287212.275429,
    "circulating_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "total_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "max_supply": null
  }
};

console.log(obj["BTC"]);
console.log(obj["ETH"].price);

Object.keys(obj).map((value,key)=>{
   console.log(obj[value]);
   console.log(obj[value].price);
}
                  )
```

You were right. But you need access object using['value']

Comment: that was the most logical path indeed, thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `for..in` loop?, you can loop object with `for...in`. You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
const parent = {
  "BTC": {
    "price": 13322.848306438736,
    "percent_change_24h": 2.00659441,
    "market_cap": 246870460628.15366,
    "volume_24h": 33956399259.1725,
    "circulating_supply": 18529856,
    "total_supply": 18529856,
    "max_supply": 21000000
  },
  "ETH": {
    "price": 380.8150073343507,
    "percent_change_24h": -0.67132589,
    "market_cap": 43115533610.355606,
    "volume_24h": 15706287212.275429,
    "circulating_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "total_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "max_supply": null
  }
}

for (const key in parent) { // This is just O(n)
  // key - BTC,ETH
  console.log(parent[key].price)
  console.log(parent[key].percent_change_24h)
}
```

Comment: Yes that works for mapping all of them but you cannot access them one by one like this :
getBTC= () =>{
    for (const key in this.state.dataApi.BTC) {
      console.log("bitcoin",this.state.dataApi[key]["price"],this.state.dataApi[key]["percent_change_24h"],this.state.dataApi[key]["market_cap"])
    }
 
}

and i use for loop i get an empty answer!

Comment: Above solution iterates one by one only, you just need to replace `parent` with `this.state.dataApi`. And time complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with `Object.keys`. There's another method called [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values) that gives you the values **for each** key of the object.

If our object is `data`, then `Object.keys(data)` will give us a two-value array/. Afterwards, we could, for example iterate with `map()` to get all prices:

```
Object.values(o).map(d => d.price)
```

```js
let o = {
  "BTC": {
    "price": 13322.848306438736,
    "percent_change_24h": 2.00659441,
    "market_cap": 246870460628.15366,
    "volume_24h": 33956399259.1725,
    "circulating_supply": 18529856,
    "total_supply": 18529856,
    "max_supply": 21000000
  },
  "ETH": {
    "price": 380.8150073343507,
    "percent_change_24h": -0.67132589,
    "market_cap": 43115533610.355606,
    "volume_24h": 15706287212.275429,
    "circulating_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "total_supply": 113219103.1865,
    "max_supply": null
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(o))
```

Comment: yes that works too but for only for mapping not to select one element, for exemple only the "BTC" and then access its details :
  Object.values(this.state.dataApi).map(d => console.log(d.btc.price))

Comment: In that case, use Object.values() on the selected element: `Object.values(this.state.dataApi.BTC)`, giving you an array with each property of the BTC.